# Toggle component without changing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `Scroller` which I don't control which takes in data as a prop.

This data is a list of objects. Within object, one of the keys takes in a function.

This component has ability where upon clicking on the square, I am meant to show a new component (like a pop up).

The component Scroller which I don't control taking in the data prop.

```
<Scroller
    data={getData(allData)}
/>
```

This is the data being passed in. content is a list of objects.

```
  const getData = (content) => content.map((c, i) => ({
    header: c.header,
    customOnClick: (() => {
      setClicked(true); // this is the line which resets the scroll
    }),
  }
  ));
```

So this works as intended. Upon clicking, the new pop up content shows. This is due to state change via the `setClicked` function.

The issue is that this Scroller component has a scroll option. So user could have scrolled pass a a block (0) like following image.

[image]

But the moment I click the button to show the popup, it resets the scroll position back to 0 like following. Instead of remaining in position as above.

[image]

`This scroll reset is the issue.`

This is being caused by the call to setClicked function. It doesn't matter if I do anything with it. As long as I call it, it resets.

Showing the popup component is not the issue. The mere call to setClicked is the issue.

Thus wondering if there a way I could toggle showing the pop up component without having to set state?

Or a way to maintain the scroll position without resetting the scroll.

Note that in this instance I am using hooks. It is the same outcome if I use Redux. Please advice.

This is my component which I can control.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import Scroller from 'comp-external-lib';
import PopUpComponent from './PopUpComponent';

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
  const { allData } = data;

  const getData = (content) => content.map((c, i) => ({
    header: c.header,
    customOnClick: c.customOnClick && (() => {
      setClicked(true); // this is whats causing the reset for scroll
    }),
  }
  ));

  return (
    <Fragment>
     <Scroller 
        data={getData(allData)}
      />

      {
          {/* Doesn't matter if this is commented out. The scrolling will still reset due to call to setClicked function */}
          {/* isClicked && <PopUpComponent /> */}
      }

    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:
Each time `setClick` is called, the value of `isClicked` is changed, which causes `MyComponent` to be reevaluated. Since `allData` is initialized inside `MyComponent`, it will be reinitialized each time `MyComponent` is reevaluated. Another issue is that the `data` being sent to `Scroller` is the result of a function that takes in `allData`. Each time `MyComponent` is reevaluated, that function will run again and return a new array instance given the new `allData` instance. This means that every time `MyComponent` reevaluates, `Scrollbar` gets a new instance of `data`, causing anything that consumes `data` inside of `Scrollbar` to also be reevaluated.

Solution:
My suggestion would be to utilize react's `useMemo` hook (docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to 'memoize' the data going into `Scroller`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Scroller from 'comp-external-lib';
import PopUpComponent from './PopUpComponent';

const MyComponent = ({data}) => {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);

  const scrollerData = React.useMemo(()=> {
   return data.allData.map((c, i) => ({
      header: c.header,
      customOnClick: c.customOnClick && (() => {
        setClicked(true); // this is whats causing the reset for scroll
      }),
    }
    ));
  },[data])

  return (
    <>
     <Scroller 
        data={scrollerData}
      />

      {
          {/* Doesn't matter if this is commented out. The scrolling will still reset due to call to setClicked function */}
          {/* isClicked && <PopUpComponent /> */}
      }

    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Also fun fact, `<>` is shorthand for React's `Fragment`

Comment: You are right as in the object is being recreated when I click to show the pop up. And after adding useMemo. It is only called once now. But unfortunately the issue with the scroll reset remains.

Comment: I have a console log inside the scrollerData function. It only prints once now at start. When I click and pop up comes out no further print outs after using useMemo. Unlike before where it printed each time the pop up occurs. But as said, the scroll reset issue remains though.

Comment: Are you defining the `Scroller` component? I'd be happy to debug it if you can share. It sounds like the issue is coming from that component as a side effect of a box being clicked.

Comment: Added the code for the Scroller component. Note that there is a lot in there though most are just style related. Appreciate you looking into it. Also note that this is in Typescript. Advice if you need more of the internal components called inside Scroller too. Unsure if those are relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that each time you click the component your `Scroller` gets a different reference of the data and because of that, it calls lifecycle methods that cause your performance issue.
If you will send the same props ( same reference ) to `Scroller` it should not call any lifecycle method which propably causes your problems.

```
import React, { Fragment, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import Scroller from 'comp-external-lib'
import PopUpComponent from './PopUpComponent'

const MyComponent = props => {
  const [isClicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
  const { allData } = props.data

  const getData = content =>
    content.map((c, i) => ({
      header: c.header,
      customOnClick:
        c.customOnClick &&
        (() => {
          setClicked(true)
        })
    }))

  const scrollerData = useMemo(() => getData(allData), [allData])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Scroller data={scrollerData} />

      {isClicked && <PopUpComponent />}
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: You are right as in the object is being recreated when I click to show the pop up. And after adding useMemo. It is only called once now. But unfortunately the issue with the scroll reset remains.

Comment: I have a console log inside the getData function. It only prints once now at start. When I click and pop up comes out no further print outs after using useMemo. Unlike before where it printed each time the pop up occurs. But as said, the scroll reset issue remains though.

Comment: Then you should share us more code instead of disliking the answers :)

Comment: Added more code. Wasn't the one that disliked btw. Seems all answers been disliked for some reason. Too bad can't prove  am not the one.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling getData on every render cycle and thus causing a reset of the state:
`data={getData(allData)}`

The solution will be to wrap the getData function with a useCallback hook:

```
 const getData = useCallback((content) => content.map((c, i) => ({
    header: c.header,
    customOnClick: c.customOnClick && (() => {
      setClicked(true); // this is whats causing the reset for scroll
    }),
  }
  )),[]);
```